# How can I grab an element by Id, using nightwatch.js?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

New to nightwatch.js. While writing my first tests, I cannot find conventional ways to 'grab' elements that I want to test using assertions.

Say I have an input field:

```
 <input id="myInput"></input>
```

How can I create a selector for this?

I've tried the following, which definitely is the wrong syntax:

```
 module.exports = {  
  'Initial Test': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://127.0.0.1:51260/index.html') //insert your local path 
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .assert.title('First Test')
      .expect.element('input[id=myInput]').to.be.visible;

      browser.end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Refer to the Developer Guide - http://nightwatchjs.org/guide

Comment: thank you, but that is the first place I looked. My attempt includes the css selector syntax I believe they are using. But it's not explicitly defined, or i'm overlooking the api

Comment: CSS is the default selector mechanism. To use xpath you have to key in .useXpath() and to switch back to css .useCss(). Your selector should be working or try input#myInput.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
   module.exports = {  
  'Initial Test': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://127.0.0.1:51260/index.html') //insert your local path 
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .assert.title('First Test')
      .waitForElementVisible('input[id=myInput]', 1000)
      .setValue('input[id=myInput]', 'write something')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Reference:

1. http://nightwatchjs.org/guide